serviceman / servicewoman / serviceperson etc (US)
What's the generally accepted way to refer to someone in the US military whose gender is not known (as the precise individual concerned is unknown)?
I notice that the USAF uses/used Airman as a rank for female airmen, so I am uncertain as to whether the general civilian tendency to use gender-neutral terms applies in the US military. (Note that in general I cannot assume the person concerned is in the USAF, this is just an example).
For the avoidance of doubt, I am looking for the term most likely considered polite by the military person concerned without any specific knowledge as to who they are, and this person most likely served post 2000.

No harm in serviceperson. Or soldier or hero. If I wanted to refer to the individual without knowing a thing beyond 'in the armed forces', I better go find out something. Otherwise, I'm looking for a PC term for blob. Tomb of the Unknown Soldier.

Service member is another alternative to serviceperson. No idea what people in the military think. I can't see anything in the DoD style guide, although it dislikes the term Armed Forces and prefers Military Services. (Worth considering that something like serviceperson or service member might be less clear to the general public.)

service men and women, a generic description of military personnel.

@YosefBaskin In this case I refer to things which apply to servicepersons in general (actually servicemen and women, and federal employees). I've already worked out that referring to service members as federal employees as well as perhaps being inaccurate would likely be insulting. But what more must I do as a foreign national? I'm not American, so don't want to accidentally insult people by saying something wrong, because I'm from another country.

@StuartF It's in there, under service in the usage guide on page 22.

I wonder if PhilSweet or @StuartF could write an answer quoting the DoD guide? That's pretty authoritative, I'd have thought, or at least justifiable as an authority. I'm going to follow the guide both the mention on page 22 but also the general steer to gender-neutral terms throughout the guide. But the pointer is only in comments, so I can't accept them!

@Dan I'll have you know that in Maine, women have opted for fishermen, not fisherwoman. Service men and women is completely acceptable.


SALUTE TO MILITARY SERVICE MEN AND WOMEN
service men and women
I want to begin by acknowledging not only my fellow veterans here
today, but service men and women around the world—men and women who
face grave danger with courage and strength. I want to acknowledge
those who have come before us, and those who have fallen. I also want
to acknowledge those who make a quiet and often overlooked
sacrifice—the families who are left behind.
Robert Mueller, FBI
service men and women
In order to gain an understanding of the influence of women’s service
on their family functioning, in-depth telephone interviews were
conducted with 20 civilian husbands residing in 11 states around the
U.S. Southwell and MacDermid Wadsworth discovered several key findings
for service men and women:
Purdue University

There are tons of examples.
